# Why is the character `0x62A` printed with the "Calibri" font, but the character `0x660E` isn't?

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

The `Calibri` font doesn't have neither one of the characters, `0x062A` and `0x660E`, but the first character gets printed using some other font. However, the character `0x660E` shows as an invalid char code. Why `TextOut()` doesn't substitute the font to print this last character, the same it did with the character code `0x062A` ?

If I replace the `Calibri` font by `Arial`, the result is the same.

**Edit : also I want to call your attention to this sentence, which can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx : "The Windows core fonts (Times New Roman, Courier New, Arial, Microsoft Sans Serif, and Tahoma) contain Latin, Hebrew, Arabic, Greek, and Cyrillic scripts but do not contain East Asian script characters. They link to fonts that do."** Well I've tried my code with all those fonts and the results were exactly the same : the character 0x660E is rendered invalid.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
{
    static HFONT s_hFont;   

    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            LOGFONT lf;
            memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
            lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(20, 96, 72);
            lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
            wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, L"Calibri");

            if( !(s_hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf)) ) return -1;
        }
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            s_hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(ps.hdc, s_hFont);

            wchar_t wchar1 = 0x062A;                //  Arabic character
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 10, 10, &wchar1, 1);

            wchar_t wchar2 = 0x660E;                //  Japanese character
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 10, 50, &wchar2, 1);

            s_hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(ps.hdc, s_hFont);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;


        case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteObject(s_hFont);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        default:

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0L ;
}
```

Screen shot from the output

[image]

Comment: Each individual font has its own way to represent characters that map to the character set, which is UTF-8 most of the time. If it's showing as invalid, the font may not have a character style for that symbol.

Comment: Maybe the back-up font has a glyph for `0x062A` but not for `0x660E`

Comment: The question then is how `TextOut()`s font fallback works, what fonts it uses and how that font list can be queried and changed.

Comment: @bames53 That's basically what I'm trying to understand

Comment: `0x062A` is "ARABIC LETTER TEH"; `0x660E` is a CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) ideograph. [UnicodeData.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) indicates that the range from `0x4E00` to `0x9FCC` is all CJK ideographs; it doesn't give any more information than that. It's not surprising that a font wouldn't have representations for all 20,941 characters in that range.

Comment: My concern here is about the font fallback that should be done by the function `TextOut()`, which is not occurring for the Japanese, character. Also remember what I said above, that if I replace the `Calibri` font by `Arial` the result is the same, which contradicts what's being said here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx : "The Windows core fonts (Times New Roman, Courier New, Arial, Microsoft Sans Serif, and Tahoma) contain Latin, Hebrew, Arabic, Greek, and Cyrillic scripts but do not contain East Asian script characters. They link to fonts that do."

Comment: Please follow this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/de80f208-0104-4735-8a35-7d7e8216b243) and tell me if you agree with what is being said there. Basically they're saying that, depending on the "computer configuration", one could get the character 0x660E rendered correctly using my code. Could you confirm this output ? I need an independent opinion on this, as they don't explain what do they mean by a different "computer configuration". I'm Wald B who posted that question. Thanks for your attention. Some of the answers by ColdBackup were erased from the thr

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll get a very good answer because font linking isn't terribly well documented and nobody really cares about it (for reasons I'll explain).

Michael Kaplan wrote a short series of articles on the subject:  Font substitution and linking parts [1](http://www.siao2.com/2005/03/20/399322.aspx), [2](http://www.siao2.com/2005/05/16/417711.aspx) and [3](http://www.siao2.com/2005/06/18/430507.aspx).  And there's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx).

As Michael Kaplan points out, font linking depends on the current system locale and can also be edited on any system.  You can't rely on it.

Thus any application that cares about handling multilingual text will use [MLang](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/16/185261.aspx) or [Uniscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or some other library to ensure good results.

Most applications don't need this level of international support.  Handling the user's own script is usually enough, and Windows mostly does this for you.  For example, my Japanese users want to enter Japanese text; they don't care if Urdu doesn't work on their computers.  And vice versa for users in Pakistan.

In summary, if you don't care about supporting more than the user's script, use Windows defaults.  If you do care, use a library for your text output.  Don't rely on font linking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm reading the articles you mentioned, and I'll be back as soon as I finish with this.

Comment: Consider the following sentence in the cited [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx) : "If font linking is enabled on your device, you can examine the registry by enumerating the subkeys of the registry key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE–\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink to determine the mappings of linked fonts to base fonts." (cont.)

Comment: I don't know how to verify if font linking is enabled on my machine. But it seems to be, since the Arabic character, which is not contained in the Calibri Font gets printed in my code. (cont.)

Comment: Looking at the SystemLink registry keys I can find that the Tahoma font is linked to the following fonts : MS Gothic, MS UI Gothic, MingLiU, PMingLiU, etc ... and all of these fonts contain the character 0x660E. But it doesn't get printed when I use the Tahoma font. What is the explanation for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> The Windows core fonts (Times New Roman, Courier New, Arial, Microsoft Sans Serif, and Tahoma) contain Latin, Hebrew, Arabic, Greek, and Cyrillic scripts but do not contain East Asian script characters. They link to fonts that do.

And, indeed they do link to fonts with CJK support, but that doesn't mean you have those fonts installed.  You didn't specify which version of Windows.  On older versions (e.g., XP and maybe Vista) if you install a "western" edition, you don't get good CJK font support unless you explicitly ask Windows to install the necessary fonts and tables.

There's a control panel application (Regional Settings?) that lets you indicate you want more  complete international character support.  It will require your installation media to be present, and it will install more fonts and update tables related to these additional characters.  It might even update the font linking registry keys.